# Unable to draw over app, even with explicit permission (APK25 N 7.1.1)

Tags: android, service, permissions, ontouchlistener

I am making a service that records user touch motions to add a behavioral security layer to phones.

Since Versions M+ require explicit confirmation from the user when needing SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission, I changed my code accordingly but I still get the same error

```
11-28 02:28:16.190 14410-14410/my.utar.phonesecurat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: my.utar.phonesecurat, PID: 14410
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service my.utar.phonesecurat.AuthenticationCheck@f60e3a5 with Intent { cmp=my.utar.phonesecurat/.AuthenticationCheck }: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3407)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                       Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:683)
                                                                          at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:341)
                                                                          at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
                                                                          at my.utar.phonesecurat.AuthenticationCheck.onStartCommand(AuthenticationCheck.java:71)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3390)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Here is where I ask permission:

```
public static void requestSystemAlertPermission(Activity context, int requestCode) {
        final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
            context.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }
```

And how I implement my service :

```
    public AuthenticationCheck() {
        super("AuthenticationCheck");
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Authentication service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.v("TEST","LOG CHECK++");


        mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(AuthenticationCheck.this);
        LayoutParams mLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(10,10);
        mLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);
        //mLinearLayout.setOnTouchListener(AuthenticationCheck.this);
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                10,
                10,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
        mParams.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Log.v("TEST", Boolean.toString(Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)));
        mWindowManager.addView(mLinearLayout, mParams);
        Log.v("TEST","LOG 4");

        gestureListener = new GestureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                super.onSwipeRight();
            }
        };
        mRightSwipeModel = new UserModel();
        //TODO retrieve UserModel saved
        mSwitch = false;

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, gestureListener);
        Log.v("TEST","GESTURE DETECTOR CREATED");




        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }
```

I check the permission just before the crash on the line WindowManager.addView() and get "true"in my log.

I'm really running out of options I've been searching everything regarding this issue, please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: Try inflating a layout xml instead of creating a new LinearLayout dynamically in the code

Comment: Then I should use something like:         RelativeLayout inflatedLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.inflatedLayout);  but that does not work in a service, right ? @DanielNugent

Comment: `View  view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.floating_layout, null);`    Then: `mWindowManager.addView(view, mParams);`

Comment: Not changing anything to the crashes, thanks for the lead @DanielNugent

Comment: Apparently adding a FIRST_SYSTEM_WINDOW  layout parameter besides your suggestions made the error go away. I'll keep in touch when I have more details. Thanks A LOT anyway @DanielNugent